# Does the campsite camper count as a visitor?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Every day you get one visitor like Leif or Flick or CJ or Redd etc. On the days you have a villager at your campsite, does that count as your visitor for the day? Or can you have, say, Flick on your island at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the campsite seems to be separate. Yesterday I had someone at my campsite, and Saharah still visited to sell me her wonderful mysterious rugs. So it looks like that doesn't affect the scheduling of the "regular" visitors that wander your island.